# New phonegap project always list HelloWorld

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Hello I am trying to create new android project with phonegap, but I want not to be HelloWorld
So in the console I type with this syntax: 
phonegap create [folder-name] [namespace] [project-name]

And if I type something like this:
phonegap create evilworld com.example.evilworld evilworld

phonegap create new folder named evilworld, but in the config file nothing's change!
it is again with the hellowrold stuff.

Is someone know how may I fix that because I need to create multiple projects on my machine?
Thanks

Comment: You must be making some mistake. I can see the project name I gave fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the same like PurpleDroid. The mistake must be anywhere, but not at cordova. The command seems fine. Here's a detailed explanation of how to create a Project ->

- Open Terminal
- cd ~/desktop
- cordova/phonegap create test com.example.test test
- cd /test
- cordova platform add XXXX
- cordova plugin add XXXX
- cordova build

and after that all u should have your stuff named the right way. Maybe u have to make an Update to a new phonegap version?!

Comment: When type phonegap create test com.example.test test in cmd I receive "missing library com.example.test/www/3.4.0"    and it download the helloworld from github, now I saw that , but how to fix it?

Comment: btw I install the latest phonegap

Comment: Maybe you start here first -> http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Read the Documentaion, download Cordova, install all needed software and try it again. I found your problem described in the phonegap cli documentation over here -> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli

Comment: whe I type cordova command like so - cordova platform add XXXX ti syas "cordova is not recognized as an iternal or external command program or batch file"

Comment: ...Have u read and understood the Documentation from Cordova? Do all thinks described here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface step by step.

Btw: latest version is 3.5

Comment: I install cordova and everything go fine...don't know what was the problem with phonegap isntall, but after cordova all works fine 10x

Answer (score 0):

Since a few hours research I think I found the problem. First of all I installed cordova. Second I add the git global variable. Then the phonegap project run just fine