# Phonegap Build: accelerometer not working android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Let me first start by saying that I have seen a lot of these questions, and many of them just says it `<script src="cordova-x-x-x.js"></script>` and some says not include the cordova.js file into Phonegap Build.

So I have been testing and fixing my code for some time now, and still getting the error from `onError function`. I have also copied and pasted the code from [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer).

So here's the clean code from the url:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
    }

    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in my config.xml file I have added:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing and asking the Phonegap Build crew, they showed me a code with all the functions. And this is the best way to get the accelerometer to work with Phonegap Build

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Device is Ready");
        alert(device.available);
    }

    function getAcceleration(){
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onAccelSuccess, onError);
    }

    function onAccelSuccess(acceleration) {
        var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
        element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
    }

    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    function startWatch() {
        // Update acceleration every 1 seconds
        var options = { frequency: 1000 };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onAccelSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    function stopWatch() {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
    <p>
        <button onclick="getAcceleration()">Get Acceleration</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button onclick="startWatch()">Watch Acceleration</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button onclick="stopWatch()">Stop Watching Acceleration</button>
    </p>
    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still have a problem even with this code (which I'm very sure is correct). LogCat shows I'm using a BOSCH BMA250 3-axis Accelerometer (HTC One M7) after I call watchAcceleration(...)

There are no errors that I know of... but I don't get any callbacks (no onSucces... noError either)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you try a total clean reinstall/rebuild with cordova. First off all you have to install cordova for that. If you want to know, how to get started with that you should have a look into the cordova documentation: [Cordova CLI-Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

After you installed cordova, you enter the Terminal and type in the following commands:

- cd ~/desktop
- cordova create test com.example.test test
- cd test
- cordova platform add android
- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion
- cordova build

Open the builded project in Eclipse and add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>getCurrentAcceleration</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save all and deploy the project to your device. And let me know, if this worked or not.

Comment: Im using Phonegap Build. So no need to reinstall cordova/phonegap

Comment: If you don't want to try anything, because you think, that you know that solution, then feel free to try anything, but do not ask here for help. 

Phonegap and Cordova are similar (Same codebase). But there are some differences (google that). And even if these differences are small, there is a chance to get it worked with cordova. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605033/new-phonegap-project-always-list-helloworld/24605227#24605227

Comment: Well, then I'll need to install cordova/phonegap on my computer, download Eclipse, install everything and setup a workspace etc.

Im using Phonegap Build (cloud based), so there is no option to reinstall anything. But I can try this later on, need to download everything and android sdk

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so answering instead.

In reference to above comment re "Phonegap and Cordova are similar (Same codebase)"

From http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/introduction_getting_started.md.html:

> To do so, simply ensure that the following reference is made in your
>   index.html
>
> <script src="phonegap.js">
>
> Note that this is interchangeable with
>
> <script src="cordova.js">